# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: for org.json.simple.JSONObject

Tags: java, eclipse

I have written a peiece of code that references a JSON library in my Eclipse.

When trying to Export to Jar file, I chose the option **Export Java source files and resources**.

My code is dependent on `JSONObject` library.

Now I have packaged all of my files and when I run the jar file on a linux machine, I get the ERROR::

```
# java -cp SendCommand.jar ExecuteShellComand
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/simple/JSONObject
    at ExecuteShellComand.main(ExecuteShellComand.java:19)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.json.simple.JSONObject
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 1 more
```

Unzipping my jar file yields.

```
# tree
.
├── commons-io-2.5.jar
├── ExecuteShellComand.class
├── ExecuteShellComand.java
├── json-simple-1.1.jar
├── SendCommand.jar
└── META-INF
    └── MANIFEST.MF

1 directory, 6 files
```

Although all the required files are present, I still get the ERROR. What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to separate out the `json-simple-1.1.jar` from `SendCommand.jar`.

Instead copy `json-simple-1.1.jar` and other dependent JARs into your current directory so that you can confirm that executing the following modified command works:

```
# java -cp SendCommand.jar:commons-io-2.5.jar:json-simple-1.1.jar ExecuteShellComand
```

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work. Same error. My .classpath states `<classpathentry kind="lib" path="json-simple-1.1.jar"/>`

Comment: Keep in mind that you could choose to run `ExecuteShellComand` app in two ways: (1.) using the Eclipse IDE or (2.) using the command line. The `.classpath` file entries which you listed in your comment are intended for the Eclipse IDE; they will not be read when executing from the command line which is what my answer was focused on.

Answer (score 0):

Classpath reference: Right click on project in Eclipse -> Buildpath -> Configure Build path -> Java Build Path (left Pane) -> Libraries(Tab) -> Add External Jars -> Select your jar and select OK.

Deployment Assembly: Right click on WAR in eclipse-> Buildpath -> Configure Build path -> Deployment Assembly (left Pane) -> Add -> External file system -> Add -> Select your jar -> Add -> Finish.